# Foreach Loop - Error in { : task 1 failed - "'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL'"

Tags: r, for-loop, vector, foreach, parallel.foreach

I'm new to programming in R, but i'm trying to learn parallel computing and the use of foreach.

Altough, in my case I need to loop combinations of possibilities to find the best MAPE and the best variables related to it.

I started to do nested for loops, but with 180k rows and trying to find the best combination of 3 variables it ran for 2 days straight and it didn't stop.

This the code just for 2 variables but i think you can understand the logic.

```
for (i in names(df3)) {
  for (j in names(df3)) {
  name4 = names(df3["DiasAusencia"])

  if (i != name4 && j != name4 && i != j) {
    df4 = df3[, c(i, j, "DiasAusencia")]
    H = holdout(df4$DiasAusencia, ratio = 2 / 3)
    Fi = fit(DiasAusencia ~ ., df4[H$tr,], model = "svm")
    testDf = df4[H$ts,]
    P = predict(Fi, testDf)
    MAE = mmetric(testDf$DiasAusencia, P, metric = "MAE")
    MAPE = mmetric(testDf$DiasAusencia, P, metric = "MAPE")
    res = cbind(testDf, predicted = P, MAE, MAPE)

    if (MAPE < BESTMAPE) {
      BESTMAPE = MAPE
      bestres = res
    }
    }
  }
}
```

So I've looked into the foreach documentation and tried to apply it to this problem, so I could run all the combinations possible, but with no success so far. This is my foreach code:

```
ncols = ncol(df3)

svm3 = function(var1, var2){
  if (var1 != name4 && var2 != name4 && var1 != var2) {
    df4 = df3[, c(var1, var2, "DiasAusencia")]
    H = holdout(df4$DiasAusencia, ratio = 2 / 3)
    Fi = fit(DiasAusencia ~ ., df4[H$tr,], model = "svm")
    testDf = df4[H$ts,]
    P = predict(Fi, testDf)
    MAE = mmetric(testDf$DiasAusencia, P, metric = "MAE")
    MAPE = mmetric(testDf$DiasAusencia, P, metric = "MAPE")
    res = cbind(testDf, predicted = P, MAE, MAPE)

    return(MAPE)
  }
}

sol = foreach(i=1:ncols, j=1:ncols, .combine = cbind, .packages="rminer")%dopar%{
  var1 = names(df3[i])
  var2 = names(df3[j])
  name4 = names(df3["DiasAusencia"])

  MAPE = svm3(var1, var2) 

  tmp = matrix(MAPE, ncol = ncols)

  return(tmp)
}
```

This is the error i get

> Error in { :    task 1 failed - "'data' must be of a vector type, was
>   'NULL'"

Hope you guys can help me out with this problem!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Not sure if it's your issue, but you'll need to place your function `svm3` inside the `%dopar% {..code..}` as well

Comment: It's there: "MAPE = svm3(var1, var2) "

Comment: I did this: MAPE = function(var1, var2) {...}. But it returns this: "cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'any'". I don't really understand why what I did was wrong